# React's Python-like formatted string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-router-dom

In Python you can do such a thing:

```py
string_to_format = "Hey {name}"
formatted_string = string_to_format.format(name="John")
print(formatted_string)
```

The result would be:

```sh
Hey John
```

I want to do the same in React. I know about f-strings in Python and their equivalent in ES6, but this is not the case, because f-strings need the variable that is put to string to be defined. My use case is this:

- pass a string like `/user/{userName}/details` to a component
- component creates a table in which every row is clickable (`<Link to={...} />`) and the path is determined by a value in some row's column

So for example for a row like:

```
foo 1234
```

The path would be: `/user/foo/details`. You can see the pattern.

So as I mentioned, I cannot format the string before passing it to a component because it has to be formatted deep in this child component's render function, like in a `map` statement.

Is there a way to do it in React?

P.S I use TypeScript

@Edit:

This is what I really wanna do:

I have a generic `PaginatedTable` component. It takes `columns` and `rows` lists + a configuration as props.

The configuration is as follows:

```
interface RowClickConfig {
  rowKey: string;
  to: string;
}
```

So now, `to` is put in `Link` (`import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`, so from `react-router-dom`, not a MUI one, or something like this). And normally, if I would have one table, then I wouldn't have to do this, because `to` could be specified where I actually have a variable I want to put in it like `/user/${userName}/details`. But since it's a generic table, those `to` values would differ, because one table will have users, and each row click would go to a different page with a different user, but if I want to reuse this table for, I don't know, items, then the `to` would be `/items/${itemId}` or something like this.

So when I create this config prop and pass it to my table component, I don't have a definition for a variable that will be put to `to` field. I want it to be a placeholder, like in Python, so I can later swap it with something like `.format(userName="foo")`.

Comment: you can use es6 [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Forgot to mention, I use TypeScript. When I do this, I get: `Cannot find name 'userName'. ts(2304)`

Comment: Sounds like `userName` isn't defined for use.

Comment: Like I said, I cannot define the value beforehand. Like in Python, `name` was not defined until I formatted the string on the second line. But the first line is correct. And I want the same in React

Comment: That is not how string templates work in javascript. Are you using `react-router`/`react-router-dom` by any chance?

Comment: @dabljues ok well that's not how it works in Typescript. You would do `let name='John'; console.log(\`Hey ${name}\`)`

Comment: @Nur OP wants a string defined with the format before replacing variables later dynamically. OP, I don't think there is a native way to do this. You might want to look into packages like [`string-template`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template)

Comment: ^this. I've edited my question to better explain what I want to achieve (and by the way I don't understand the downvote :( )

Comment: @dabljues, You can use this [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) lib, for more advance use...

Comment: Thanks, this looks good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath) from `react-router-dom` and do something very close.

```
import { generatePath } from "react-router";

...

const pathTemplate = "/user/:userName/details";

...

const path = generatePath(pathTemplate, { userName: 'Drew' }); // "/user/Drew/details"
```

Comment: There are also packages like [`string-template`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-template), [`sprintf-kit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-kit), [`string-kit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-kit), etc. Those are the first I found in NPM. But since OP is using `react-router-dom` (and by extension, `react-router`), this is probably the solution he wants.

Comment: This. This is what I meant! Thank you very much, works splendidly. @j1mbl3s, also thanks for pointing those out